# Setting jvmargs in log4j.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jvm-arguments

This is a bit of a weird request but I am trying to set some jvmargs in the log4j.properties file. At present I use ant to for example set some args....

jvmarg value="-Dmail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465"

... but it would be great to group a few of these logging relevant arguments into the .properties file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: log4j.properties is for configuring log4j... what makes you think you can configure the JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the properties can be added after JVM startup, you could add a property to your properties file that lists all properties that you want to add to the `SystemProperties` collection, something like:

```
# property names of system properties
systemprops=mail.smtp.port mail.smtp.socketFactory.class

mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=some.class
```

Your startup code can read the systemprops value, split on whitespace and add the resulting list of properties to the `SystemProperties` collection while reading the values from your properties collection.

This way your code does not need to know which properties to add to system props, only that the properties to add are defined by the systemprops property.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j is only going to read the properties file *after* the JVM has already started - that means it can't affect the JVM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If your example is from your actual situation then you can set this value programatically for the java mail...

> The SMTP protocol provider supports
>   the following properties, which may be
>   set in the JavaMail Session object.
>   The properties are always set as
>   strings; the Type column describes how
>   the string is interpreted. For
>   example, use
>
> ```
>     props.put("mail.smtp.port", "888");
> ```

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

This example above should work for mail.smtp.socketFactory.port also.

Comment: This is something we have looked at, but ideally we would like to keep the configuration separate from the code so we can swap in different logging systems easily at a later date...

I am trying to set:
mail.smtp.port
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port
mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback

Setting them in the ant build file is ok... but not ideal :(